# Error while adding validation rules class to binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, validationrules

I wanted to add validation rules to textBox ,the problem is that when I do the following code I got the following error message,

**A value of type 'myValidations'  cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'Collection`1'.**

The class myValidations roles is active.

What can be the problem?

```
    <TextBox x:Name="Name" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,50,0,0"  Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource tooltipError}">
        <Binding ElementName="textBlock" Path="Text">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <viewModel:MyValidationsRules/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
    </TextBox>
```

The text boxes are inherit from the following style:

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="44"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="199"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewDragEnter"
                   Handler="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewDrop"
                   Handler="DropText_PreviewDrop"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewDragOver"

        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your problem, but I think you have missed the `<TextBox.Text>` tag in your code.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,50,0,0"  Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource tooltipError}">
<TextBox.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="textBlock" Path="Text">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <viewModel:MyValidationsRules ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Finally figured it out, the example from MSDN is wrong.... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
You have to set ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" in the binding

Comment: HI Yongquan,I have tried it without success.any other idea? btw voted up for your trying to help :)

Comment: I have tried run it and it run (the error is not disabled...) and when I type on the field I get the following error:{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state. While debug I saw that the validate method called multiple times...any idea?

Comment: After More Than 3 hours trying to figure out what  is the problem(doing clean & rebuild) 

The error was gone when I close and open the VS :( .

Currently I have two issues

Now the debugger is stopped in the validate method and when I return false the field was not change the color to red,why?

2. when I write long string and  delete it with the backspace I get stack overflow exception ,how can  i avoid it?

Thanks again,

Jhon

Comment: Sorry, I've been away from desktop for a while, you can send some related codes to my email so I'll take a look. liuyongquan2010@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is that your MyValidationsRules doesn't inherit of ValidationRule or your class MyValidationsRules not override the Validate method. This class and this method must be plubics.

```
public class MyValidationsRules : ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

    }
}
```